# How do I tell how many connections db2 has active?

Tags: count, db2, database-connection, jmeter

We have an application that uses d2 as the database, it is developed externally but we wish to performance test and monitor the active connection count from jmeter.

I have looked round for sql that does this and only found the a large connection report response.

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cicsts/v4r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.cics.ts.performance.doc%2Ftopics%2Fdfht3_stats_db2_conn_0stat.html

Are there any other ways?

Comment: What platform is DB2 running on?

Comment: RHEL not sure of version, DB2 9.1

Comment: 9.1?  That's out of support since April!  Since you're paying license fees to IBM, don't you think you should be on a version that they'll support?

Comment: Probably, it is a legacy system with little to no appetite for change or risk around change.

Answer (score 2):

There is also a command to get a list with current connections: [LIST APPLICATIONS Command](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/core/r0001958.htm)